# How to covert this string into a python list?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string: x = `'[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}]'`

I want to convert this string into a list:`x = [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}]`

I tried doing this:
x = list(x)

but this returns all the characters separated by a comma.
['[', '{', "'", 'i', 'd', "'", ':', ' ', '3', '5', ',', ' ', "'", 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', "'", ':', ' ', "'", 'C', 'o', 'm', 'e', 'd', 'y', "'", '}', ']']

```
x = list(x)
```

Comment: You can use string.split
```
string.split("delimiter")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `list(x)` you get a list of individual characters of the string.

Instead you can use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) for this (You could have used [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) but you cannot since the string contains single quotes)

```
In [5]: import ast                                                                                                                                                                     

In [6]: x = "[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}]"                                                                                                           

In [7]: ast.literal_eval(x)                                                                                                                                                            
Out[7]: [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}]
```